# How to prove that the limit of this sequence is $\pi$

Tags: limits, recurrence-relations

> Given that:
>   $a_0=1,\ \ b_0=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, \ \ t_0=\dfrac{1}{4}, \ \ p_0=1$
>
> Define
>   $a_{n+1}=\dfrac{a_n+b_n}{2} \ \ , b_{n+1}=\sqrt{a_n b_n} \\ 
> t_{n+1}=t_n-p_n(a_n-a_{n+1})^2 \ \ , p_{n+1}=2p_n.$
>
> Find the limit:
>
> $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(a_n+b_n)^2}{4t_n}$$

I tried to solve the question but I couldn't find a way to start, so I calculated the values up to $10000$ and it seems to be approaching $\pi$. How do I prove it?

Comment: This is the Brent-Salamin algorithm: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Legendre_algorithm . The proof is quite involved....

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Thanks! Isn't an elementary proof possible?

Comment: If you find an elementary proof, please let me know.

Comment: "it seems to be approaching $\pi$" is called an euphemism... Haven't you seen** if you are working in multiprecision** (which is necessary) that you have thousands of exact decimals...

Comment: Missing subscript ? ... $t_{n+1}=t_n-p_n(a_{\color{red}{n}}-a_{n+1})^2$

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit Edited

Comment: @JeanMarie I just wanted to ask the same question. That thing is quadratically convergent (I was almost holding my breath when I read that article by Brent and Salamin, then, and the proof is _not_ difficult!), so $a_{10000}$ "seems to be approaching" definitely sounds a bit funny.

Comment: Limits don't approach anything. However the terms of the sequence can.

Comment: This is the formula with which I started my blogging. An elementary proof with all the details is covered in the series of posts starting with http://paramanands.blogspot.com/2009/08/arithmetic-geometric-mean-of-gauss.html you may want to read all 6 posts one after another or be content with just the last one http://paramanands.blogspot.com/2009/08/pi-and-the-agm-gauss-brent-salamin-formula.html which proves this formula.

Comment: You should also note that $t_{n} $ is the series which resembles the denominator of formula given in my post.